# Как вырезать определённое значение из строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Всем привет.

Своими мозгами, видимо, не дойду. Нужна помощь.
К примеру, у меня есть переменная, `var` со значением `'MNP_RHEL_v1.1_notification76'`. 
Вопрос заключается в следующем. Каким образом можно написать регулярное выражение, которое будет обрабатывать полученное значение переменной `var` и будет обрезать всё, кроме `notification` (и возможных других значений ? напр. `'MNP_RHEL_v1.1_aps76', 'MNP_RHEL_v1.1_pure76'`, где надо будет вытащить `aps` и `pure`).

Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и без регулярок:

```
result = ''.join(c for c in var.split('_')[-1] if not c.isdigit())
```

или так:

```
import string

t = str.maketrans('', '', string.digits)
result = var.split('_')[-1].translate(t)
```